# Configure middleware in react-scripts start

Tags: reactjs, express, react-scripts

I am very new to development with reactjs. I am using the react-scripts library (using an existing react app) and have the following package.json script:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "lint": "eslint src/**/*.{js,jsx}",
    "lint:fix": "eslint src/**/*.{jsx,js} --fix"
  }
```

I understand that when I run `npm run start`, the library will automatically start the server on `http://localhost:3000`. Previously, I was using express-js to start my server and need to add the following middleware in my new app:

```
const { setup } = require(‘radiks-server’);

setup({mongoDBUrl:"...." }).then((RadiksController) => {
app.use(’/radiks’, RadiksController);
});

app.listen(port);
console.log("Listening on port ", port);
```

Where should I add this in the new app such that the react-scripts library knows to use this middleware when it starts its server on `http://localhost:3000`.

Thank You.

Comment: [CRA](https://create-react-app.dev) (the react-scripts you're using) doesn't come with server to server APIs on afaik. You need to run your own.

Comment: In your npm scripts you could do `"start": "react-scripts start && node server.js",` where the `server.js` script is your express server

Comment: Okay. So, should I shift all my functionalities that involve the `radiks-server` to my own server (using express-js) or should I change the current implementation of the project (from CRA to express-js). My app mostly uses radiks functionalities. I don't exactly know how middleware is actually bound with the server which actually servers my code. I have just followed the [radiks documentation](https://docs.blockstack.org/data-storage/integrate-indexing#configure-your-application-to-use-your-radiks-server) for my express app as well. Thanks for the reply!!

Comment: As far as I understand, the radiks-server middleware needs to be configured with the server that is hosting my app (because it uses client-side auth and other functionalities). So, can I use the same port for my express server as well. If not, how should I do this?